# Criar um api teste de mapa

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando criar um api de map, tentei um Key do google para teste, e não estou conseguindo, gostaria de saber se tem alguma alternativa, sendo outros sites ou o google mesmo?

segue o codigo abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDcG1mbGY_EnypGSBBdoG1GdGA74puz0GU&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você ja viu o log no console?

Comment: Adiciona o seu site no Google Cloud Plataform para autorizar a usar o googlem maps

Comment: estou em localhost, sera que esse é o problemas?

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta, sou iniciante ainda, mas como assim o " log no console"??

Comment: No chrome ou firefox você pressiona F12 e vê o console. Que erro dá...